# Cannot load font-face in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, font-face

started with the vuejs hello world but cannot make the font-face load. 
anyone else had the same issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one worked for me:

`src: url('~@/assets/fonts/rajdhani-light-webfont.woff') format('woff');`

Answer (score 0):

define your path like this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'rajdhanibold';
    src: url('../fonts/rajdhani-bold-webfont.eot');
    /* and another sources */
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer @Milad ! i've added `@import "@/assets/styles/_fonts.scss";` in `vue.config.js` and now getting this error: `These relative modules were not found:`

Comment: your welcome! working with CSS Pre-processors is like walking on thin ice. you can follow these commands : https://css-tricks.com/how-to-import-a-sass-file-into-every-vue-component-in-an-app/ I hope can help